# Contributing to Tor

Tags: help

I've been interested in contributing to the Tor project for some time now, having read the option for contributing:

- "Create a poster around a theme, such as "Tor for Freedom!""

I'm interested in developing a few different "Tor for freedom" posters. However i'm unsure what I would do with them after creating them.

Answer (score 0):

It is nice that you are interested in spreading word about TOR.

I suggest that, if possible, you spend some money or set up a donation campaign to print high quality physical posters in a digital printing company. Then you could attach these posters everywhere in your city.

You could attach them to,

- Universities and high schools
- Train and bus stations
- Market places and public walls
- Public toilets

Or you can make also little flyers and give them to people at your city.